# phpmyadmin - Login issue, takes me back to the login page after logging in

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'd setup phpmyadmin quite a while ago and it worked well and I got everything setup and working etc... However, I went to login recently and it always just takes me back to the login page. The credentials are correct, but never the less I always end up at the login screen.

I can't find anything in my error logs, and in the access logs everything is status code 200, except the POST which is 302 followed by 304s. None of that really stands out.

I'm using Nginx+PHP5-FPM+MySQL if that changes anything.

What types of things might I have changed that would cause this sort of activity?

Comment: Is the database up and running?

Comment: Yes. It and the website that uses it are running just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was memcache. I'd added it for other reasons and set PHP to use it for sessions. Nothing broke (or so I thought) and all seemed well. Turns out it's this very reason phpMyAdmin was not working. phpMyAdmin does not support memcache being used for sessions in PHP, it requires files.